# Why initialData() Realm is never called when setting up configuration?

Tags: kotlin, realm

First, I would like to ask you, if you think that this question deserves -1, be honest enough and please explain why.

This is the code for Application class:

```
class WeatherApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()    
        Realm.init(this)
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(
            RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .initialData(DatabaseInitTransaction(applicationContext))
                .build()
        )

    }
}
```

This is the transaction class:

```
class DatabaseInitTransaction(private val applicationContext: Context): Realm.Transaction {

    override fun execute(realm: Realm) {
        Log.d("DatabaseInitTransaction", "execute called.")
        val cityDao = CityDao(realm)
        realm.deleteAll()
        var stream :InputStream? = null
        try {
            stream = applicationContext.assets.open("city.list.json")
            cityDao.createAllFromJson(CityEntity::class.java, stream)
        } catch (thr: Throwable) {

        } finally {
            stream?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

So, on cold start method `execute()` of `DatabaseInitTransaction` class is never get called. I could not figure out why, please, help!

Comment: did you call getDefaultInstance() after this code?

Comment: `initialData()` will only be run if the Realm file does not yet exist on the disk. Maybe you should clear application data first on your test device?

Answer (score 0):

You must check first your Custom Applicatiom Class name is written in Manifest file.

in

```
<Application>
```

tag with Class name

Comment: I did. That was the next thing I did after creating that class.

Comment: did you add line .getInstance(config) ?